# A question about $S^{-1}R\otimes_R M\cong S^{-1}M$ as $S^{-1}R$-modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

I have found this online notes from Columbia University. However, I have a question (maybe very silly) about the proof.

**It says that by the universal property, the map $f'$ induces a unique $S^{-1}R$-module homomorphism. But should it be an $R$-module homomorphism?**

I think maybe I messed up with the universal property. I always assume that if we have an $R$-bilinear map from $M\times N$ to $L$, then it induces an $R$-module homomorphism from $M\otimes_RN$ to $L$. How could we induce a $S^{-1}R$ homomorphism if we have $\otimes_R$ instead of $\otimes_{S^{-1}R}$?

[image]

PS It says that the map $f'$ is bilinear. In the sense of $S^{-1}R$-bilinear or $R$-bilinear? I suppose it should be the latter, is it?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are 100% right that the map induced by the universal property is, a priori, just an $R$-linear map.

However, the following lemma shows it doesn't matter:

**Lemma.** Let $f: M \to N$ be an $R$-module map, where $M$ and $N$ are $S^{-1}R$-modules. Then in fact $f$ is $S^{-1}R$-linear.

This is because $s f(\frac{r}{s} m) = rf(m) $ in $N$, so, multiplying both sides by $1/s$ gives that $f$ is $S^{-1}R$-linear.

Comment: ah thank you ! I was being stupid!

Comment: not stupid -- I think the book is saying something misleading.

Comment: @hunter Can you please also explain why $S^{-1}A\otimes_A M$ is an $S^{-1}A$-module?

Comment: @Atom good question, and actually that doesn't have anything to do with localization. 

If $B$ is an $A$-algebra -- which means it is an $A$-module that is also a ring, with the compatibility condition that $a(bb') = (ab)b'$ --  then $B \otimes_A M$ is a $B$-module. The $B$-module structure is just coming from by multiplication on the left-hand-side.