# tensor product and localization of module

Tags: commutative-algebra

$M$ be $\mathfrak m^{-1}R$ module where $\mathfrak m$ be maximal ideal in a ring $R$

I want to show that: $\mathfrak m^{-1}R \otimes_R M$ is isomorphic to $M$

First: I define a map
$f$:  $\mathfrak m^{-1}R \otimes_R M$ $\to$ $M$ by  ($\frac{r}{s}\otimes $m$ $) $\to$ $\frac{r}{s}$m
and the inverse map by
$g$: $M$ $\to$ $\mathfrak m^{-1}R \otimes_R M$ by m $\to$ $\frac{1}{1}$ $\otimes$m

However $f \circ g$ is identity, but $g \circ f$ is not, since $\frac{r}{s}$ $\otimes$m $\to$ $\frac{r}{s}$m $\to$ $\frac{1}{1}$ $\otimes$ $\frac{r}{s}$m

Note that if we define the $\mathfrak m^{-1}R \otimes_R M$ be $\mathfrak m^{-1}R$ module by $\frac{r_1}{s_1}$ ($\frac{r}{s}\otimes $m$ $)=$\frac{r_1r}{s_1s}$ $\otimes$ m, we have no condition to show that $\frac{1}{1}$ $\otimes$ $\frac{r}{s}$m = ($\frac{r}{s}\otimes $m$ $) since we are tesoring with R module, can any one help me ? thanks

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathfrak m^{-1}R$?

Comment: It means the localization or you can say $R_m$

Comment: $$\frac{r}{s}\otimes m=\frac{r}{s}\otimes s\frac{m}{s}=\cdots$$

Comment: More general, if $M$ is an $S^{-1}R$-module, then $S^{-1}R\otimes_RM\simeq S^{-1}M\simeq M$. (For the first isomorphism see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2966998)).